# GWT - How to serialize JSON response into array and loop it to be shown in table

Tags: java, json, gwt

I have simple response from a page in JSON format which looks like this:

```
{"ip": "89.164.255.124"}
```

This is a trivial example from http://ip.jsontest.com/ that I am using only to learn how to do it.

I need to serialize that response into array and then then run a loop to show it in a table. This needs to be done in Java.

Comment: Have you checked this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java ?

Comment: Check out: http://www.g-widgets.com/2016/08/25/serializingdeserializing-json-in-gwt/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: @LLL The OP is asking for the GWT environment.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject("{ 'ips': [ { 'ip': '192.168.0.1' }, { 'ip': '192.168.0.2' }, { 'ip': '192.168.0.3' } ]}");
    JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("ips");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("ip"));
    }
}
```

}

Ref :

Comment: Can org.json wotk in GWT environment?

Answer (score 0):

I always use GWT Jackson.

I found it much clearer how to use than working with JSONObject, JSONArray and stuff like that.